# /clock topic not recived on master

Tags: ros, roscore, ros-indigo, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a G-mapping based SLAM robot .

**Master - This is my desktop .**

- roscore is running here
- 192.168.1.6 is the IP address

**Robot - The robot is hooked to a RPI3 .**

- I have added this to the .bashrc file , "export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.6:11311"
- IP address of the RPI is "192.168.86.165"

I am publishing /clock (which is required for the node publishing /odom) from the RPI on the *Robot* .

I am not able to receive the /clock on the *Master* .

**Essentially the client is not able to communicate back with the master , how do i fix it .**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281979//clock-topic-not-recived-on-master/) by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you set `ROS_IP` on both hosts?

---

Edit:

> Should i set the ROS_IP on both Master and Client ?

Unless you have a working DNS setup for both: yes.

Note: if you have DHCP configured, adding the (current) IP addresses to `/etc/hosts` is not sufficient, as the IPs may change in the future / on reboot. If you have DHCP, make sure to have proper DNS as well (ie: updated by your DHCP server).

And just making sure: have you checked the [ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) guide?

---

Edit2:

> On the robot instead of `export ROS_IP=192.168.86.165`, it was `export ROS_IP=localhost`

I would be very much surprised if that works. It could work now, but I guarantee you that you'll get in trouble later.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on 2018-02-07**:
Should i set the ROS_IP on both Master and Client ?

**Comment by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on 2018-02-07**:
Thanks , problem solved .
On the robot instead of export ROS_IP=192.168.86.165 , it was export ROS_IP=localhost